# Class 'CI_Driver_Library' not found codeigniter error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want  to use session, so I try to do autoload. In application > config.php, I do `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');`

but I got below error

```
Message: Class 'CI_Driver_Library' not found

Filename: Session/Session.php
```

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks again man! so weird why can't the previous init doesn't work anymore?    $this->load->library('session');

Comment: Made a answer! (driver >= version 3.0 and library <= version 2.1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your using Codeigniter `3.0` or higher use this:

```
$autoload['drivers'] = array('session');
```

Because the `session` is a `driver` not a `library` after version 3.0!

Under Version `2.1` it's a `library`!

Answer (score 0):

application/config/autoload.php

just to add to @Rizier123 answer.

Answer (score 0):

file: url/`application/config/config.php`

`CI Verson` less than `3.0` have given `cache` and `session` as `library` functions.

> $autoload[`'libraries'`] = array(`'cache'`,`'session'`);
>
> $autoload[`'drivers'`] = array();

And for Verson 3.0 and greater

> $autoload[`'libraries'`] = array();
>
> $autoload[`'drivers'`] = array(`'cache'`,`'session'`);

**remove both from library** and then simply add it to **drivers** You might **forget** it to remove from `library`, this causes proper loading after resolving the problem;